# how to bind firebase data to fullCalendar with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-plugins, firebase, fullcalendar

I'm trying to bind data from FireBase to my fullCalendar plugin in angular.
but it seems that the plugin doesn't like `data.$asObject()` or `data.$as Array()`.

this is what I have so far which doesn't work (no meetings are displayed):

Controller:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("myCal");
    app.controller('meetingsCtrl', meetingsCtrl);

    function meetingsCtrl($scope, $http, $location, $firebase) {

        var ref = new Firebase(firebaseurl); // real url
        var meetings = $firebase(ref);

        $scope.fireEvents = meetings.$asObject(); // $asArray() not working as well

    } // controller func

})();
```

Directive:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("myCal");

    app.directive("sbCalendar", function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                $(element).fullCalendar({

                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    aspectRatio: 4,
                    events: scope.fireEvents,
                    editable: true,
                    eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {

                    } // event drop

                }); // fullCalendar init & options

            } // link

        } // return 
    }); // directive
})();
```

the json file I uploaded to Firebase (the fb url is pointing to meetings ):

```
{
    "meetings": {
        "x1": {
            "title": "test subject",
            "start": "2016-10-20",
            "end": "2016-10-20",
            "description": "some long description test"
        },
        "x2": {
            "title": "test2 subject",
            "start": "2016-11-05",
            "end": "2016-11-06",
            "description": "another long description for test 2"
        },
        "x3": {
            "title": "test3 new subject",
            "start": "2016-11-11",
            "end": "2016-11-11",
            "description": "yet another description for test 3"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("myCal");
    app.controller('meetingsCtrl', meetingsCtrl);

    function meetingsCtrl($scope, $http, $location, $firebaseArray) {
        var ref = new Firebase(firebaseurl); // real url
        $scope.fireEvents = $firebaseArray(ref);
    }

})();
```

This is the newer syntax - make sure your using the latest angular fire release, as of writing this, on the firebase site they have the 1.1.3 cdn available.

Check out more here:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html

```
app.directive("sbCalendar", function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.fireEvents.$loaded(function(){
                $(element).fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    aspectRatio: 4,
                    events: scope.fireEvents,
                    editable: true,
                    eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {

                    } // event drop

                }); // fullCalendar init & options
            })

        } // link

    } // return 
}); // directive
```

Comment: Do you get an error or does the data simply not display?

Comment: no errors, just not displaying. I do see the object when I log it.

Comment: I see, I think the issue is the data is not synced when the directive is compiled.  You could try adding the $loaded method to bind the data to the fullCalendar plugin only after the data is gathered.

Comment: good one mate, I have tried that $load method on the controller side before pushing it to the scope but I guess I need to do it your way :) so thanks, it works now.

Comment: one question though.. you said `$firebaseArray` is a new syntax... it means that `$asArray` and `$asObject` is deprecated?

Comment: Yea - check it out here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/migration-guides.html

Comment: thanks, though that approach with the `$load` is now putting me in a new problem, now the view doesn't change or sync when I delete objects from the firebase db or create new objects with `$add`... I need to refresh the page to see the changes